# Wordpress add_action from another class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

This is my code:

```
class Show
{
    public function error()
    {
        add_action('admin_notices', [$this, 'pip1']);
    }

    public function pip1() {
        echo '
            <div class="notice notice-success"><p>test</p></div>
        ';
    }
}

(new Show())->error();
```

Top code works fine and print errors.

But if I use this code in another class, it doesn't work.

Example:

```
class Manager extends Controller
{
    public function add()
    {
        (new Show())->error();
    }
}

(new Manager())->add();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include class file first before call it.

```
class Manager extends Controller
{
    public function add()
    {
        require_once('path/to/class_Show/Show.php');
        (new Show())->error();
    }
}

(new Manager())->add();
```